# Error can't install pip or python

Tags: lubuntu, python

When typing this following command:

```
python
```

I am getting the following message in Ubuntu 17.10:

```
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:

 * python-minimal
 * python3
```

And when typing these command `python3 -V` it tells me that it is `python3.6.3`?

Why is that happening?

When I type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But pip seems not to be installed, when I try:

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Comment: The command should be `python -V`, but run `which python` lets see if python is there!

Comment: Does `which python` command show any output ?

Comment: yes    The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:

python-minimal
python3

Comment: No sir just paste the output into your question! You don't have python installed. If you did the result would have been `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Did you remove it by any chance?

Comment: when typing these command( python3 -V)    i am getting              python3.6.3

Comment: @George no that behavior is perfectly normal 17.10 has no python2.7 installed by default.

Comment: @Videonauth are you serious,  boy lots of surprises in 18.04 next year!

Comment: Yep I'm serious about that, Ubuntu has no system features anymore based on python 2.7. Quote "Python 2 is no longer installed by default. Python 3 has been updated to 3.6." from [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes)

Comment: Then thi sis a really unusual  Ubuntu, however use then `pip3`. Wonder if you actually have read my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

That behavior is perfectly normal for Ubuntu 17.10 as it contains no python 2.7 by default anymore

> Python 2 is no longer installed by default. Python 3 has been updated to 3.6.
>   (from [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes))

The right line to use is:

```
python3
```

Beside that you can install pip for python 3.6 with the following command

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

This will install pip for python 3 which you can call with ***`pip3 <command>`*** or `pip <command>` (which does not seem to work in your case no clue why).

And for python 2.7 including its pip if you so wish with the following command:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 python-pip
```

To call pip for python 2 you need to use `pip2 <command>`.

Comment: just re check my question i tryed sudo apt install python3-pip  but i think it did not resolve the problem of pip

Comment: an re check my answer ;) Use `pip3 install BeautifulSoup`

Comment: thanks it saved  (i taught to go for previous version of ubantu)

Comment: @mdvenkatesh You can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside it if this solved your problem. Beside that you not need `sudo` for installing something with `pip3`.